# Plank Dock to use image instead of color?

Tags: dock, plank

I was wondering if it's possible to make the plank dock use an image as a background instead of a solid/transparent color? As far as I can see, the plank dock themes are composed of some kind of html/rgba color code thingy. Is there any way to make it use an image instead of colors?

Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the developers of Plank, this is currently (November 2015) not possible.

Source: https://answers.launchpad.net/plank/+question/253191

Comment: Maybe you could add a link or quote of the source of this information? That would improve the answer's quality. And consider accepting your own answer if you think that the question can be declared as solved.

Comment: I just added the source.. Feel free to mark it as solved.

Comment: @LinunxDudester You must mark it as solved yourself by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left of this answer. Nobody else can do this. :-)